# More console information on error in xcode

Tags: xcode, console, assertion

Hi I've got this error in my console :

```
2012-05-25 15:42:32.157 Mehdi Bensafi[426:f803] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:1021
```

But I want more information, is it possible ?

For example I've seen some complete error message like this :

```
An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 3 deleted). with userInfo (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `backtrace` (or `bt`) command on the console.